# How to mock Knex using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, knex.js

I am trying to mock knex using jest for below implementation

```
 const knex = Knex({ client: "mysql"})

    const query = knex("table_name")
      .where({
        title: "xxx-yyy",
        lang: "eng"
      })
      .select()
      .orderBy('date', 'desc')
      .toSQL()
      .toNative()
```

Below I tried but it didn't work and getting error "TypeError: knex is not a function"

```
jest.mock("knex", () => {
  return () => {
    return {
      knex: () => {
        where: () => {
          select: () => {
            orderBy: () => {
              toSQL: () => {
                toNative: jest.fn()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I really appreciate any help on this please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jest.mock()` will mock a module with an auto-mocked version, `factory` and `options` are optional.

You can use [mockFn.mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) to mock the method chaining calls.

Besides, if you initialize `Knex` inside the module scope, you need to `require` the module after mock is set up.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import Knex from 'knex';

const knex = Knex({ client: 'mysql' });

export function main() {
  const query = knex('table_name')
    .where({
      title: 'xxx-yyy',
      lang: 'eng',
    })
    .select()
    .orderBy('date', 'desc')
    .toSQL()
    .toNative();
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import Knex from 'knex';

jest.mock('knex');

describe('68717941', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const querybuilder = {
      where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      toSQL: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      toNative: jest.fn(),
    };
    const mKnex = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(querybuilder);
    Knex.mockReturnValue(mKnex);
    const { main } = require('./');
    main();
    expect(Knex).toBeCalledWith({ client: 'mysql' });
    expect(mKnex).toBeCalledWith('table_name');
    expect(querybuilder.where).toBeCalledWith({ title: 'xxx-yyy', lang: 'eng' });
    expect(querybuilder.select).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(querybuilder.orderBy).toBeCalledWith('date', 'desc');
    expect(querybuilder.toSQL).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(querybuilder.toNative).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68717941/index.test.js (8.844 s)
  68717941
    ✓ should pass (7464 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.439 s
```

Comment: Getting error: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type 'typeof knex'

Comment: Please help to resolve this issue ^^, thanks

Comment: it works well, but not with knex.raw() method passed to knex.select()

Comment: Knex.mockReturnValue line is not a thing, this answer is made up, dont waste your time.

Comment: As said in other comments, `Knex.mockReturnValue(mKnex)` will not work (at least with typescript). However, you can fix it by using the module factory instead: `jest.mock('knex', () => jest.fn(() => mockKnex));`.
Also, you will have to declare `mKnex` and `queryBuilder` before importing any file that may import knex otherwise you will get a `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mKnex' before initialization`.
@Lin Du Can you update your answer please ?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout a small lib that I've written [knex-mock-client](https://github.com/felixmosh/knex-mock-client), which allows you to write a unit tests that uses DB without real DB :].

The benefit of this method, is that you don't need to know all `Knex's` internal (which may change overtime) and it allows you control what data your "DB" should return for a specific query.

An example of usage:

```js
// my-cool-controller.ts
import { db } from '../common/db-setup';

export async function addUser(user: User): Promise<{ id }> {
  const [insertId] = await db.insert(user).into('users');

  return { id: insertId };
}
```

```js
// my-cool-controller.spec.ts
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';
import knex, { Knex } from 'knex';
import { getTracker, MockClient } from 'knex-mock-client';
import faker from 'faker';

jest.mock('../common/db-setup', () => {
  return {
    db: knex({ client: MockClient })
  };
});

describe('my-cool-controller tests', () => {
  let tracker: Tracker;

  beforeAll(() => {
    tracker = getTracker();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    tracker.reset();
  });

  it('should add new user', async () => {
    const insertId = faker.datatype.number();
    tracker.on.insert('users').response([insertId]);
    
    const newUser = { name: 'foo bar', email: 'test@test.com' };
    const data = await addUser(newUser);

    expect(data.id).toEqual(insertId);

    const insertHistory = tracker.history.insert;

    expect(insertHistory).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(insertHistory[0].method).toEqual('insert');
    expect(insertHistory[0].bindings).toEqual([newUser.name, newUser.email]);
  });
});
```